# Clickhouse frequently dies and comeup automatically

Tags: clickhouse

clickhouse running in K8s as a stateful set dies frequently and coming up automatically. Following call trace is seen error log file of clickhouse.

https://pastebin.com/m1N54vHy

Startup of clickhouse.

https://pastebin.com/EwVKpP12

Can anyone please help to understand what's wrong with the setup?

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE graphite_index

Query id: ed03eae3-c9d1-4f42-a061-d790460ce3ef

┌─statement──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ CREATE TABLE default.graphite_index
(
    `Date` Date,
    `Level` UInt32,
    `Path` String,
    `Version` UInt32,
    `updated` DateTime DEFAULT now(),
    `status` Enum8('SIMPLE' = 0, 'BAN' = 1, 'APPROVED' = 2, 'HIDDEN' = 3, 'AUTO_HIDDEN' = 4)
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/single/default.graphite_index', 'clickhouse1-0', updated)
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(Date)
ORDER BY Path
SETTINGS index_granularity = 1024 │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


SHOW CREATE TABLE graphite

Query id: 95f64ef9-3154-4c04-9d0f-11d706469429

┌─statement──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ CREATE TABLE default.graphite
(
    `Path` String CODEC(ZSTD(2)),
    `Value` Float64 CODEC(Delta(8), ZSTD(2)),
    `Time` UInt32 CODEC(Delta(4), ZSTD(2)),
    `Date` Date CODEC(Delta(2), ZSTD(2)),
    `Timestamp` UInt32 CODEC(Delta(4), ZSTD(2))
)
ENGINE = Distributed('graphitereplica', '', 'graphite', xxHash64(Path)) │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: init.sql file https://pastebin.com/r8YytVin

Comment: I bet your pod is killed by OOM killer. Check kernel messages.

Comment: resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "4"
            memory: 8Gi

Above resources are allocated to POD. 

Prometheus container_memory_working_set_bytes and container_memory_rss both plotted in below panel not showing memory even near to the limit value. I can see they are max reaching upto 3-4GB.

Comment: share clickhouse-server.log

Comment: Created a new clickhouse setup to simply the troubleshooting. In new setup only single node clickhouse is deployed. Still crash is happening. JFYI, I am running one delete cron to delete the metrics older than certain time. 
```
│ CREATE TABLE default.graphite
(
    `Path` String,
    `Value` Float64,
    `Time` UInt32,
    `Date` Date,
    `Timestamp` UInt32
)
ENGINE = GraphiteMergeTree('graphite_rollup')
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(Date)
ORDER BY (Path, Time)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/m6fFxXjr  This is the call trace visible clickhouse error log everytime during the crash. Then application starts up with the message https://pastebin.com/W6WBb5eu